# How to solve this recurrence$f(n)=A\cdot f(n-1)+B\sum{f(i)f(n-i)},\;1\leq i\leq n-1,$ and $f(1)=K$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$f(n)=A\cdot f(n-1)+B\sum{f(i)f(n-i)} , \;1\leq i\leq n-1,$ and $f(1)=K$.

Is $f(n)$ similar to Catalan number equation $C(n+1)=\sum{C(k)\cdot C(n-k)}$?

If yes then how to solve above  recurrence?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question and suggestions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737957/how-to-solve-following-recurrence-equation-fn-sum-limits-i-1n-1fn-i)

Answer (score 1):

For
$f(n)=a f(n-1)+b\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(i)f(n-i)
$
for $n \ge 2$,
using generating functions
seems appropriate.

Let
$F(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)x^n
$
with
$f(0) = 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
F^2(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)x^n\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} f(m)x^m\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)f(n-k)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(k)f(n-k)\\
\end{array}
$

Also,
$xF(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)x^{n+1}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n-1)x^{n}
=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(n-1)x^{n}
$.

Therefore
$F(x)-xf(1)
=axF(x)+bF^2(x)
$.
Letting
$F(x)
=xG(x)
$,
this is
$xG(x)-xf(1)
=ax^2G(x)+bx^2G^2(x)
$
or
$bxG^2(x)+(ax+1)G(x)+f(1)
=0
$.

(Note - I mistakenly had 
$ax-1$.)

Solving for $G$,
$G(x)
=\dfrac{1-ax\pm\sqrt{(ax+1)^2-4bxf(1)}}{2bx}
=\dfrac{1-ax\pm\sqrt{a^2x^2+2(a-2bf(1))x+1}}{2bx}
$.

I'll stop here
and let someone else
get the coefficients.

(But see below
where I go a little further.)

Note that
if $a=0$,
this is
$G(x)
=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{-4bf(1)x+1}}{2bx}
$,
so if
$a=0, b=1$
this is
$G(x)
=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{-4f(1)x+1}}{2x}
$
which gets us
into Catalan land.

---

We have
$G(x)
=\dfrac{1-ax\pm\sqrt{a^2x^2+2(a-2bf(1))x+1}}{2bx}
$.

Expanding just the first term,
$G(x)
=\dfrac{1-ax\pm(1+(a-2bf(1))x+O(x^2))}{2bx}
$.
For this have
$G(0)$ exist,
we have to take the
negative sign,
so
$G(x)
=\dfrac{1-ax-(1+(a-2bf(1))x+O(x^2))}{2bx}
=\dfrac{x(-2a+2bf(1))+O(x^2))}{2bx}
=\dfrac{(-a+bf(1))+O(x))}{b}
=\dfrac{-a}{b}+f(1)+O(x)
$.

To see why 
the full expansion is so messy,
consider that
$\sqrt{1+y}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}y^k
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{1+ux+vx^2}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}(ux+vx^2)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}x^k(u+vx)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}x^k\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}v^jx^ju^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^k\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}x^{k+j} \binom{k}{j}v^ju^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n-j+1}}{4^{n-j}(2(n-j)-1)}\binom{2(n-j)}{n-j} \binom{n-j}{j}v^ju^{n-2j}
\qquad(k = n-j)\\
\end{array}
$

This is what you need
(assuming no mistakes on my part)
to get the expansion of
$f(n)$.

Now I'll really stop.

Comment: thanks for help ,but can you please tell final equation of f(n) ?

Comment: Not easily. When $a=0$, the expansion of $\sqrt{1+cx}$ gives the Catalan numbers. In this case, there would be a nested binomial theorem expansion. Instead of $(cx)^n$ in that sqrt expansion, there is $(ux+vx^2)^n$.

Comment: I did the expansion.